# using two arguments on one of them integer on check_output

Tags: python, arguments, args

Hello please to compile a program that i'm using i use in the terminal the command:

```
python3 pp.py cholesky.c --args "m.mtx.txt 1400" --verbose
```

i use two arguments as you can see a file m.mtx.txt and 1400 but now i need to use it in a python-script using check_output to use differtent ints from 1400 so i use this loop

```
for i in range(1400, 2500, 100):
        i = str(i)
        check = check_output(["python3", "pp-.py", "cholesky.c","--args", "m.mtx.txt", i, "--verbose"]).decode('ascii')
```

but it didn't work and that's return the message:

```
    check = check_output(["python3", "pp-fpmp.py", "cg.c","--args", "m.mtx.txt", i, "--verbose"]).decode('ascii')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python3', 'pp-fpmp.py', 'cg.c', '--args', 'm.mtx.txt', '1400', '--verbose']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

please, i can really use some help.

Comment: There's an error message, have you checked it? As we are not sure what python script you're executing does, we can only guess what return code `2` means.

Comment: Run the command yourself directly, and see what error it produces.  `python3 dd-fp2mp.py cg.c --args 494_bus.mtx.txt 1400 --verbose --debug`

Comment: There is a difference between `'--args', '494_bus.mtx.txt', '1400'` and `'--args', '494_bus.mtx.txt 1400'`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing the `--args` parameter the same way as:

```
python3 dd.py cholesky.c --args "494_bus.mtx.txt 1400" --verbose --debug
```

`"494_bus.mtx.txt 1400"` should be one parameter, such as:

```
check = check_output(["python3", "dd.py", "cholesky.c","--args", f"494_bus.mtx.txt {i}", "--verbose", "--debug"]).decode('ascii')
```